# azure-search-openai-demo-csharp does not deploy correctly to azure clooad

Tags: azure, azure-devops, openai-api

I want to try the sample, which Microsoft provided about the azure search.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo-csharp.

I have all rights, what are needed for creating this sample

- Access to Azure OpenAI Service
- Owner of the subscription

but the deployment always fails. I have two different errors. Sometime everthing works without any issues except the "redis" resource and sometimes the "openai"-resource already fails.

### redis error

{
"code": "ContainerAppOperationError",
"message": "Failed to provision revision for container app 'redis'. Error details: Operation expired."
}

### openai error

"error": {
"code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
"message": "The template deployment 'openai' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '****-****-****-****'. See inner errors for details.",
"details": [
{
"code": "InsufficientQuota",
"message": "Insufficient quota. Cannot create/update/move resource 'cog-******'."
}
]
}

Any ideas why this errors occurs?

I also tried the python sample, with the same openai error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already fixed the issues.

### redis error

Now this timeout error does not occur anymore. Not 100% sure what the issue was.

### openai error

Resources like OPEN AI have in the overview a section "show deleted resources". And those resources still blocking "quotes". After deleting these resources via "purge" everything worked as expected again.

Comment: how you deployed all the resources. Can we deploy all the resources one by one and what all permission required for all different services.